# Storage for abstract things?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Are there any synonyms or alternatives for the words *store/storage* in context of storing abstract things? For example:

> **storage** of user's posts
>
> to **store** functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try *space* or *repository* or *warehouse*. *Stockpile* works both as a verb and a noun, as do *hoard*, *cache*, or *reserve*.

Answer (score 2):

*Archive* works well with abstract items, especially computer terminology.